# Как выбрать элемент первый или допустим, пятый, из списка восьми элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выбрать элемент первый или допустим, пятый, из списка  восьми элементов?

---

Вот так мы выбираем все **'a'** элементы , которые находятся внутри **#id_nav_conteiner**  и **li**.

```
var $arr[0] = $("#id_nav_conteiner").children('li').children('a').attr('id', 'id_nav');
```

---

**Вопрос:** Как выбрать например пятый элемент или четвертый?

Хочется сделать так `children[0]('li')`, но так не работает:

```
var $arr[0] = $("#id_nav_conteiner").children[0]('li').children('a').attr('id', 'id_nav');
```

Comment: Вы слишком мудрите :) что бы добраться до a, которые в li которые в элементе id=id_nav_conteiner достаточно `$("#id_nav_conteiner li a")`. "A" в 5м "li" примерно так `var elm=$("#id_nav_conteiner li")[4]; $("a",elm).`  Самое главное, что после применения любой функции, когда возвращается JQ объект, в нем есть массив DOM элементов. Но это DOM, что бы с ними опять работал JQuery надо сделать с ними `$(elm)`

Comment: @Mike Это установка атрибута - .attr('id', 'id_nav'); Спасибо. Попробую. Вы если что ответ можете написать, а я со своей стороны вам "спасибку" поставлю.

Comment: @Mike  Пока не работает что бы находить по порядку.var elm=$("#id_nav_conteiner li")[4];

Comment: А вы в консоли, например у хрома набирайте и смотрите что возвращает. Сначала просто $("#id_nav_conteiner li") убеждаетесь что там их много. добавляете [4] смотрите что получилось. только последующий $ не забывайте применить. Т.е. если кратко то 5й li $($("#id li")[4])

Comment: @Mike Не-не.... Я пишу что это - var elm=$("#id_nav_conteiner li")[4]; не работает из-за нарушения синтаксиса тут [0]

Comment: @Mike Во Заработало. Спасибо  А как также сделать но с помощью - children('li').?

Comment: @Mike Ааааааааа.. Так это точка входа же $(). А как на JS сделать без Jqury?

Comment: @Mike Зачем мы еще оборачиваем в еще одну точку входа?

Comment: @Mike, ну зачем брать dom-элемент по индексу и снова его оборачивать? Есть же `eq`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так я с JQuery дней 5 назад вообще первый раз познакомился, причем как обычно методом научтного тыка. поэтому ответ и не писал, подозревал что проще должно быть :)

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов JQuery объекты, которые собственно представляют весь функционал, включают в себя массивы найденных элементов, но это массив DOM-элементов, а не JQuery. так что либо начинаем работать с ними как с нативными javascript DOM элементами, либо опять оборачиваем в JQuery. Ну, или читаем наконец документацию, что бы узнать про более прямые методы, как предложил Qwertiy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Хочется сделать так `children[0]('li')`

а надо так `children('li').eq(0)`

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста. Я так понимаю что в любом JQury скрипте нужно указывать эту конструкцию -   `$(document).ready(function(e) {}`  Что бы точно быть уверенным что все пройдет гладко загрузиться до конца все DOM древо?

Comment: А то я писал без этой конструкции.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, во-первых, она заменяется `$(function($){`. Во-вторых, можно и без неё быть уверенным. Но лучше пиши, раз не разобрался.